# mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт авторизации пользователей

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    // делаем запрос к БД
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("money", $link) or die (mysql_error());
    // и ищем юзера с таким логином и паролем

    $query = "SELECT `id`
            FROM `vxod`
            WHERE `login`='{$login}' AND `password`='{$password}'
            LIMIT 1";
    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // если такой пользователь нашелся
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
        // то мы ставим об этом метку в сессии (допустим мы будем ставить ID пользователя)

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
 $linkus = "sdsdsdsd";
 echo $linkus;

    }
    else {
        die('Такой логин с паролем не найдены в базе данных. И даём ссылку на повторную авторизацию.');
    }
}
session_start()
?>

Что тут значит вот это?
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1)
```

И еще как убирать форму авторизации после входа пользователя?

Comment: Чисто ради прикола вбейте `mysql_num_rows` в гугл

Comment: И вы увидите яркий пример уличной магии!11!АДИН

Comment: Sh4dow и ты туда же? =(( чесслово, Ale_x тоже в одну строчку уложился.

Comment: Куда туда же, чего не так?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_num_rows` - возвращает количество строк который вернул сервер MySQL на ваш запрос

```
session_start()- кстати нада поместить в самое начало скрипта!
Пароли храните в зашифрованном виде - щас они у вас открыты, да и запрос на проверку авторизации подвержен SQL инъекции - что совсем не хорошо
```